# website load time is too long because of too many image links on the main page

Tags: modal-dialog, overlay, singlepage, page-load-time, hugo

I have a website that is built using Hugo Static site generator. The theme I have used is called [Dimension](http://themes.gohugo.io/dimension/) and is a single page theme. I have a number of pages each written in a markdown file (.md file) but when I use hugo it combines all the files in the `index.html`. The theme uses overyal (modals) to create different pages. [Here](http://themes.gohugo.io/theme/dimension/#) is an example of how it works and looks. Here for example if you click on `INTRO` link you go to this URL: `http://themes.gohugo.io/theme/dimension/#intro` and the content of `intro` is inside intro.md file. So the `INTRO` page is called modal or overlay.

As I have a lot of links to web images (about 1000) and as all of them are placed in `index.html' it takes a long time to load, although I don't need all of them at once. Is there a way to load only images that are needed for a specific overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the Lazysizes script. It's lightweight and powerful: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

Comment: Indeed it is very helpful. It improved the loading speed of my site significantly. Thanks for the answer.